# Problems with implementing return on recursive function with Julia

Tags: julia

I have implemented the next code for going down and right in a grid, and I am trying to implement some sort of counting like return +1 but I can't, if I'm forced to use global it makes the runtime considerably longer (like times 8 though it varies with the number of iterations).
Please advise on how to code correctly in this language.

I also thought about using pointers like in C but had hard time implementing it

```
function numOfPaths(NominalSize,x,y)
    (x < NominalSize) && numOfPaths(NominalSize,x+1,y)
    (y < NominalSize) && numOfPaths(NominalSize,x,y+1)
    (x >= NominalSize && y>=NominalSize) && global count+=1;
end
count = 0;
t1 = @elapsed numOfPaths(16,0,0)
```

2nd version with Ref instead of using global, pretty much same horrible performance.

```
function numOfPaths(NominalSize,x,y)
   (x < NominalSize) && numOfPaths(NominalSize,x+1,y)
   (y < NominalSize) && numOfPaths(NominalSize,x,y+1)
   ((y >= NominalSize) && (x >= NominalSize)) && (ref[] += 1 ;)
end
count = 0;
ref = Ref(count)
t1 = @elapsed anse = numOfPaths(15,0,0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the current state of the Julia compiler I think you have two options (assuming you do not change the logic of your code).

The first one is leave things as they are in your code, but change `count` to be a global `const`. However, as you want to mutate it you have to introduce some wrapper, a natural one is `Ref`. So you can go with something like:

```
const count = Ref(0)
function numOfPaths(NominalSize,x,y)
    (x < NominalSize) && numOfPaths(NominalSize,x+1,y)
    (y < NominalSize) && numOfPaths(NominalSize,x,y+1)
    (x >= NominalSize && y>=NominalSize) && global (count[] +=1)
end
count[] = 0
@time numOfPaths(16,0,0)
count[]
```

Now you could pass around `count` like this:

```
function numOfPaths(NominalSize,x,y, count=Ref(0))
    (x < NominalSize) && numOfPaths(NominalSize,x+1,y, count)
    (y < NominalSize) && numOfPaths(NominalSize,x,y+1, count)
    (x >= NominalSize && y>=NominalSize) && (count[] +=1)
    return count[]
end
```

as a parameter, but it will be a bit slower.

Finally (and this is an option that is a bit faster than the first one and is recommended) you can perform the accumulation of `count` without passing it as an argument (this time it will be just an integer):

```
function numOfPaths(NominalSize,x,y)
    count = 0
    x < NominalSize && (count += numOfPaths(NominalSize,x+1,y))
    y < NominalSize && (count += numOfPaths(NominalSize,x,y+1))
    x >= NominalSize && y>=NominalSize && (count+=1)
    return count
end
```

---

**EDIT:**

Additionally let me comment on what does not work. Naturally you would want to rewrite your function like this:

```
function numOfPaths(NominalSize,x,y)
    function f(x, y)
        x < NominalSize && f(x+1,y)
        y < NominalSize && f(x,y+1)
        x >= NominalSize && y>=NominalSize && (count+=1)
    end

    count = 0
    f(x, y)
    return count
end
```

Unfortunately, currently such code is slow, as Julia is boxing `count`:

```
julia> @code_warntype numOfPaths(16, 0, 0)
Variables
  #self#::Core.Compiler.Const(numOfPaths, false)
  NominalSize::Int64
  x::Int64
  y::Int64
  f@_5::Core.Box
  count@_6::Core.Box
  f@_7::Union{}
  f@_8::Union{}
  count@_9::Union{}

Body::Any
1 ─       (f@_5 = Core.Box())
│         (count@_6 = Core.Box())
│   %3  = Main.:(var"#f#3")::Core.Compiler.Const(var"#f#3", false)
│   %4  = Core.typeof(NominalSize)::Core.Compiler.Const(Int64, false)
│   %5  = Core.apply_type(%3, %4)::Core.Compiler.Const(var"#f#3"{Int64}, false)
│   %6  = f@_5::Core.Box
│   %7  = %new(%5, NominalSize, %6, count@_6)::var"#f#3"{Int64}
│         Core.setfield!(f@_5, :contents, %7)
│         Core.setfield!(count@_6, :contents, 0)
│   %10 = Core.isdefined(f@_5, :contents)::Bool
└──       goto #3 if not %10
2 ─       goto #4
3 ─       Core.NewvarNode(:(f@_8))
└──       f@_8
4 ┄ %15 = Core.getfield(f@_5, :contents)::Any
│         (%15)(x, y)
│   %17 = Core.isdefined(count@_6, :contents)::Bool
└──       goto #6 if not %17
5 ─       goto #7
6 ─       Core.NewvarNode(:(count@_9))
└──       count@_9
7 ┄ %22 = Core.getfield(count@_6, :contents)::Any
└──       return %22
```

Hopefully in the future this will get resolved (it is a known issue).

---

**EDIT 2**

First let me comment what to do if you wanted to make this code run faster. In this case instead of recursion one can use dynamic programming, e.g.:

```
function numOfPaths(NominalSize, x, y)
    y, x = minmax(x, y)
    a = ones(BigInt, NominalSize + 1 - y)
    for i in 2:NominalSize - x + 1
        i > length(a) || (a[i] = 2 * a[i])
        for j in i+1:length(a)
            a[j] += a[j-1]
        end
    end
    return a[end]
end
```

(note that I am using `BigInt` here, as with this code you can test values that are much larger than the range of `Int64` type; if you would want to be even faster just switch `BigInt` to `Int` in the code, but then for `NominalSize` greater than `33` you will get an overflow)

---

Now, going to the question of @Alex Zh why the second code runs slowly. You can run `@code_warntype` on it to learn the following:

```
julia> function numOfPaths(NominalSize,x,y)
          (x < NominalSize) && numOfPaths(NominalSize,x+1,y)
          (y < NominalSize) && numOfPaths(NominalSize,x,y+1)
          ((y >= NominalSize) && (x >= NominalSize)) && (ref[] += 1 ;)
       end
numOfPaths (generic function with 1 method)

julia> count = 0;

julia> ref = Ref(count)
Base.RefValue{Int64}(0)

julia> @code_warntype numOfPaths(15,0,0)
Variables
  #self#::Core.Compiler.Const(numOfPaths, false)
  NominalSize::Int64
  x::Int64
  y::Int64

Body::Any
1 ─ %1  = (x < NominalSize)::Bool
└──       goto #3 if not %1
2 ─ %3  = (x + 1)::Int64
│         Main.numOfPaths(NominalSize, %3, y)
└──       goto #3
3 ┄ %6  = (y < NominalSize)::Bool
└──       goto #5 if not %6
4 ─ %8  = (y + 1)::Int64
│         Main.numOfPaths(NominalSize, x, %8)
└──       goto #5
5 ┄ %11 = (y >= NominalSize)::Bool
└──       goto #9 if not %11
6 ─ %13 = (x >= NominalSize)::Bool
└──       goto #8 if not %13
7 ─ %15 = Base.getindex(Main.ref)::Any
│   %16 = (%15 + 1)::Any
│         Base.setindex!(Main.ref, %16)
└──       return %16
8 ─       return false
9 ─       return false
```

Now in the line:

```
%15 = Base.getindex(Main.ref)::Any
```

you see that when Julia fetches `ref` from `Main` it does not know what is its type, as it is a global variable that is not a constant. Therefore the compiler is not able to generate an efficient machine code, as the type of `ref` has to be resolved at run time (not at compile time).

Now consider the following change (you need to restart Julia to test it):

```
ulia> function numOfPaths(NominalSize,x,y)
          (x < NominalSize) && numOfPaths(NominalSize,x+1,y)
          (y < NominalSize) && numOfPaths(NominalSize,x,y+1)
          ((y >= NominalSize) && (x >= NominalSize)) && (ref[] += 1 ;)
       end
numOfPaths (generic function with 1 method)

julia> count = 0;

julia> const ref = Ref(count)
Base.RefValue{Int64}(0)

julia> @code_warntype numOfPaths(15,0,0)
Variables
  #self#::Core.Compiler.Const(numOfPaths, false)
  NominalSize::Int64
  x::Int64
  y::Int64

Body::Union{Bool, Int64}
1 ─ %1  = (x < NominalSize)::Bool
└──       goto #3 if not %1
2 ─ %3  = (x + 1)::Int64
│         Main.numOfPaths(NominalSize, %3, y)
└──       goto #3
3 ┄ %6  = (y < NominalSize)::Bool
└──       goto #5 if not %6
4 ─ %8  = (y + 1)::Int64
│         Main.numOfPaths(NominalSize, x, %8)
└──       goto #5
5 ┄ %11 = (y >= NominalSize)::Bool
└──       goto #9 if not %11
6 ─ %13 = (x >= NominalSize)::Bool
└──       goto #8 if not %13
7 ─ %15 = Base.getindex(Main.ref)::Int64
│   %16 = (%15 + 1)::Int64
│         Base.setindex!(Main.ref, %16)
└──       return %16
8 ─       return false
9 ─       return false
```

Now I have made `ref` a global `const`. This tells the compiler that `ref` is guaranteed not to change its type. Therefore you have:

```
7 ─ %15 = Base.getindex(Main.ref)::Int64
```

as this time the compiler has all type information it needs, so a much more efficient machine code can be generated.

Comment: last option is the best option

Comment: By last Matt B. means the accumulation of count (after I added comment on what is recommended it is not last). I agree that the last option is the best. In particular option 1 is not thread safe, but I have shown it, as the original code used globals.

Comment: Who are you so wise in the ways of the code.
That was really helpful, I looked for answers for couple of hours, came with another way but it was slower, is possible explain why please. and thanks for the original answer!

I used after the function count = 0 ; ref = Ref(count); and later changed the value of ref in the function but it was as slow as the global variation I showed, how come your version with Ref is significantly faster?

Comment: Can you post in your question your solution with `Ref` - then I can try to comment why it was slow and in my answer I will try to also comment how you can diagnose such things in practice.

Comment: Sure, That will be amazing, I'm coming after a course in uni doing C and loved it, but it is much easier to code algorithms in Julia. Ill post in a minute

Comment: Once again thank you for taking the time and answering. I learned a lot more than I hoped for and its thanks to you! I sort of understand now one of the reasons why C is considered one of the fastest as you need to declare types on everything. And that lazy writing may cause big performance issues.

Answer (score 0):

I found a Pkg that uses cache, runtime for 20 NominalSize is 0.0002673 [sec]
doing it without cache takes about 20 [min] for same size

so its Bogumił Kamiński answer + memoization

```
using Memoization
@memoize function numOfPaths(NominalSize,x,y)
   count = 0
   x < NominalSize && (count += numOfPaths(NominalSize,x+1,y))
   y < NominalSize && (count += numOfPaths(NominalSize,x,y+1))
   x >= NominalSize && y>=NominalSize && (count+=1)
   return count
end
t = @elapsed paths = numOfPaths(20,0,0)
```

Comment: Well - I assumed this was a question about the language design. If you want algorithmic improvement then one can use e.g. dynamic programming. I will add an example of such a solution in my answer.